# how can i load contact inside collection in firebase with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

when I add a collection in Firebase and name it collection when I click on add list but still empty in the collection because the text editing controller does not work correctly how can I work it.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
import 'package:elraydeon1/screens.dart/individualpage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class ContactFetch extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenroute = "ContactFetch";
  const ContactFetch({super.key});

  get displayName => null;
  get phones => null;

  @override
  State<ContactFetch> createState() => _ContactState();
}

class _ContactState extends State<ContactFetch> {
  TextEditingController displayName = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController phones = TextEditingController();

  CollectionReference contact =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Contact');

  Future<void> addlist() {
    // Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new user
    return contact
        .add({
          'Name': displayName.text, // John Doe
          'Phone': phones.text, // Stokes and Sons
        })
        .then((value) => print("List Added"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _askPermissions();
  }

  Future<void> _askPermissions() async {
    PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await _getContactPermission();
    if (permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      _handleInvalidPermissions(permissionStatus);
    }
  }

  Future<PermissionStatus> _getContactPermission() async {
    PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;
    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted &&
        permission != PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permission.contacts.request();
      return permissionStatus;
    } else {
      return permission;
    }
  }

  void _handleInvalidPermissions(PermissionStatus permissionStatus) {
    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      const snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Access to contact data denied'));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    } else if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      const snackBar =
          SnackBar(content: Text('Contact data not available on device'));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
  }

  Future<List<Contact>>? reqContact;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Contacts List'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                addlist();
                setState(() {
                  reqContact =
                      ContactsService.getContacts() as Future<List<Contact>>?;
                });
              },
              child: const Text("Load Contact")),
          Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: reqContact,
                  builder: (context, snp) {
                    if (snp.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                      var contacts = snp.data;

                      if (contacts != null) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: contacts.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              Contact contact = contacts[index];

                              return ListTile(
                                title: Text(' ${contact.displayName}'),
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  child: Text("A"),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Text(contact.phones?.single.value ??
                                    "not found"),
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                                      context, Individualpage.screenroute,
                                      arguments: {
                                        'title': '${contact.displayName}'
                                      });
                                },
                              );
                            });
                      }
                      return Container();
                    }
                    return Container();
                  })),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

how can i load contact inside collection in firebase with flutter  how can i load contact inside collection in firebase with flutter

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure what your asking but if your wondering why nothing gets added to the firebase document is because you never linked your text controller to any inputs. Try adding this.

```
TextField(
      controller: displayName,
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Display Name'),
),
TextField(
      controller: phones,
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Phone Number'),
),
```

Comment: @AbdelrahmanHashem add them in the column/children widget, if you want to have specifik inputs see documentation for textfield widget here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html

Comment: thanks@william98111, I want to load the contact list I will leave a screenshot for my run code in comment https://ibb.co/VL9nz6j need this list when I pressed on load contact this list upload to firebase